# Redirect folder in subdomain to a new folder in a new subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a all content in a folder on a subdomain to a new folder on a different subdomain but not getting it to work.

Trying to redirect: 
sub1.domain.com/dir to sub2.domain.com/res

I've tried different methods that I've found on here but not successful so far - and is the redirect going into the .htaccess file for the root or for the subdomain?

Hopefully someone can guide me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write a RewriteRule to do that for you. First, you can use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/KYidop/1) and find a regular expression. Then, in your .htaccess file, you can add your RewriteRule, maybe something similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)sub1\.domain\.com\/dir$ $1sub2\.domain\.com\/res$ [L,R=301,NE]
</IfModule>
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)sub1\.domain\.com\/dir$ $1sub2\.domain\.com\/res$ [L,R=302,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Every time you make a change in .htaccess file, you want to clear your browsing history, and test it to see if it works.

[image]